# How to make Parity work on my PC. "Parity can't run on your pc"

Tags: ether, parity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, parity-wallet

My blocks freeze at around the 760,000 mark, therefore I downloaded Parity's latest version to which I then received the message above. I have downloaded multiple versions of Parity to try and fix the error, so that I can run my ETH Wallet and receive ETH which I have purchased.

I haven't found anyone with the same issue so far, however I have seen a plethora of videos which describe how to download and run Parity with ETH wallet, and I followed these to the T. Therefore I cannot understand what is wrong.

- ASUS Notebook
- 2GB RAM
- I have 3GB free storage
- Running Windows 10

If my specs are the issue, are there any suggestions to overcome this problem as I have paid for my ETH and not received as yet due to non-functional Wallet. If I bought it and sent it to my Wallet address before the block-data was fully downloaded will it clear my purchase so that I have wasted my money?

Comment: can you provide logs? What does it say when you run `parity ui` ?

Comment: how do I do this? complete newbie you see haha

Comment: just run in `cmd.exe` `parity --log-file /path/to/parity.log ui`

Comment: This version of C:\Program Files\Ethcore\Parity\parity.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.           I attempted to use what you suggested but it said it was unable to find Parity

Comment: did you run it from `cmd.exe` I don't also think you are using the right path to parity.exe

Comment: 3 GB of free storage may not be enough to hold the entire chain

Comment: I think the specs of your machine is too weak to run comfortably geth or parity. I'd suggest to use a wallet like MyEtherWallet.

Answer (score 1):

Parity is not available for 32 bit versions of Windows.

But it's on the long wishlist, you can track it here: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/5692

It will be probably faster to upgrade all your systems to 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

ETH should already be in your wallet, you can check the balance in your wallet address here: https://etherscan.io/